# Running ASP.NET IHostedService before API is ready

Tags: asp.net-core

What would be a good solution to run some code during code initialization, before the API is ready?

I need access to IoC in this code, and preferably if this code fails the API shouldn't even finish starting.

Today I am running an `IHostedService` with a flag somewhere indicating it succeeded, then I have a middleware watching that flag and if it didn't finish properly I short-circuit any requests to the API, but it seems more complex than it should be.

I remember seeing some change in the behavior of IHostedServices, in which they would run synchronously during startup, so that the order they were registered matters. But I cannot find this information anywhere now, not sure if it is my mind playing tricks on me.

Comment: iirc, IHostedService will run synchronously until it reaches async code. Other options would be to run the code after the IoC builds (`var app = builder.Build();`) but before running the pipeline (`app.Run();`). Another would be to rely on a ready checks, if your infra supports to, so your app isn't "ready" to serve traffic until your IHostedService completes

Answer (score 1):

> I remember seeing some change in the behavior of IHostedServices, in
> which they would run synchronously during startup, so that the order
> they were registered matters. But I cannot find this information
> anywhere now, not sure if it is my mind playing tricks on me.

According to your description and scenario, you got it right that the behavior of IHostedService has changed in ASP.NET Core 3.0 and later versions. In those versions, hosted services are started asynchronously by default, and the order of registration doesn't necessarily determine the order of execution during startup.

> I need access to IoC in this code, and preferably if this code fails
> the API shouldn't even finish starting. in that case What would be a
> good solution to run some code during code initialization, before the
> API is ready?

If you need to run some code during the initialization and if you want to  access to IoC and potentially prevent the API from starting if this code fails,

In that scenario, create a class that implements IHostedService to encapsulate your initialization code. Then in the constructor of your IHostedService, inject any services you need from the IoC container. This grants you full access to them within your initialization logic. Finally, within the StartAsync method, execute your initialization tasks, utilizing the injected services as needed.

Let's have a look how we can implement that in practice:

```
public class InitializationService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ISomeService _someService; 

    public InitializationService(ISomeService someService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            
            await _someService.DoSomethingAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
            logger.LogError(ex, "Initialization failed. Halting application startup.");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**   As you can see I have Injected `ISomeService` do the same the services you need. After that perform initialization tasks using injected services within `StartAsync`

Program.cs:

Within your program.cs file register your service as following:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<InitializationService>();
```

Following above way, if any failure occurs during initialization, throw an exception within StartAsync. This halts the application startup process, preventing the API from becoming available.

In addition, handle exceptions appropriately within your initialization logic.

**Note:** Keep in mind, this is not the exact solution of your issue but one of the way to handle the scenario. If you still have any more concern on this, I would highly recommend you to post new question along with reproducible sample so that it can be investigate accordingly. Please [refer to this  official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio) this might be [insightful for you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio).

**Upate:**

As saying above is your current approach, then  As a simpler alternative, you could set a manual flag in your configuration file during initialization.

Then, your API middleware or controllers could read and act upon this flag to disable itself or throw exceptions if initialization fails.

Apart from that, If your initialization logic is relatively simple and only interacts with other middleware, consider creating an early middleware that executes before your API endpoints.

Alternative way:

```
public class InitializationMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IMyService _myService; 

    public InitializationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IMyService myService)
    {
        _next = next;
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _myService.InitializeAsync(); 
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (InitializationException ex) 
        {
            
            logger.LogError(ex, "Initialization failed.");
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError;
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Initialization failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any further assistance on this.

Comment: This is what he is doing now, how is this an answer. He is looking for another way if possible.

Comment: He has not share us about his current approach yet,  you are saying he is doing like this. That's fine, we then now try another way.

Comment: Anyway, we can also  create an early middleware that executes before your API endpoints or manually flag within configuration file during initialization.